# How can I make dependency injection'd code comfortable to both use and test?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

I'm getting started on PHP so please excuse my code if I'm doing something horribly wrong.
Let's see this method I have for an "insurance" object, that would give me back all of the clients that have said insurance:

```
public function getBeneficiarios() {
        $petitionsVariables = array(
            PeticionDeCoberturaColumns::COBERTURA_ID => $this->getId()
        );
        $petitions = (new PeticionDeCoberturaDAO())->getByValues($petitionesVariables);
        $clientes = array();
        foreach ($petitions as $petition) {
            $clientes[] = $petition->getClient();
        }
        return $clientes;
    }
```

Said code clearly isn't very testable, since it's coupled to a specific DAO. In order to properly test it, I'd need to mock the DAO and inject the mock.

The dependency injection way to do it would have been

```
public function getBeneficiarios($dao) {
        $petitionsVariables = array(
            PeticionDeCoberturaColumns::COBERTURA_ID => $this->getId()
        );
        $petitions = $dao->getByValues($petitionesVariables);
        $clientes = array();
        foreach ($petitions as $petition) {
            $clientes[] = $petition->getClient();
        }
        return $clientes;
    }
```

I could inject the DAO on the insurance object constructor, but I don't like the idea of passing an unrelated DAO simply because it needs to be used on a single method.

Every time I want to use the getBeneficiarios method, I'd need to first create the DAO, and it sounds very, very, counter intuitive. Future coders shouldn't have to bother about that.

How could I keep both a comfortable to use code, and a comfortable to test code?

Comment: "I could inject the DAO on the insurance object constructor, but I don't like the idea of passing an unrelated DAO simply because it needs to be used on a single method." - if the class only needs the DAO for a subset of its functionality small enough to make you think it's unrelated, maybe it should be split up.

Comment: You mean doing something like creating a ClientsFinder class with a findByInsurance() method?

Comment: That said, "comfortable to use" and "comfortable to test" seem to be at odds. Good, loosely coupled factoring tends to lead to many highly specialised classes, which is inherently onerous to wire together and more difficult to wrap your head around completely. You usually counter this by making this finely grained structure an implementation detail, and layering a more convenient API surface over it.

Comment: Yes, that's an option. To use more formal terms, your original class seems to violate the single responsibility principle. Personally I tend to place finder methods into the DAO layer, unless the DAOs aren't customizable.

Comment: Thanks. What's your opinion on passing the implementaton of getBeneficiarios to that ClientFinder class, and in order to keep its use simple, keep that getBeneficiarios() method with a "new ClientFinder()->getByInsurance($this->getId(), new ClientDAO())" method inside?
I wouldn't be able to test it, but I'd be able to test the ClientFinder class instead.

Comment: Give me one second, I'm putting in PasteBin for an easier review.

Comment: That seems like a overusing method injection. If `ClientFinder` is stateless, just create one when your script starts up, and pass it the DAO through the constructor. You should obviously also inject the insurance object with the client finder. This way, the insurance object, which if I'm reading this correctly is a "fat model" object, would also serve as an API facade over the other architecture tiers.

Comment: This is what I was talking about http://pastebin.com/WmAmSKG8 . 
About passing the DAO through the constructor, let's say that I make a new method in the ClientsFinder called "getByCity" . Wouldn't I have to modify the current constructor to get both a petitions DAO and a cities DAO now? 
Your solution of moving it to the DAO's seems wise, but I'd have to create half mocks or make use of a testing DB in order to test said code.

Comment: I think we're getting to the point where the answer is very likely to be "it depends". If you have several different ways to find clients (i.e. retrieve them through insurance applications, or filter them by city directly), then it makes sense to have a separate class dealing with this. Usually, the client DAO is sufficient to do this, but it seems things are more complicated in your model. So creating a `ClientFinder` that has both the petitions DAO and the cities DAO is a good option if you don't feel like moving all this logic into the client DAO.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean about "half mocks" though. When mocking, it's perfectly all right to mock only the methods that the unit being tested needs.

Comment: It's okay, I got confused by the half mocks part.
You've been pretty helpful, thank you. I'll pass the functionality to the DAO.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is not the testability of your class, it's the design of your application.

In true DDD, your class shouldn't depend on the DAO, or even know that it exists. You can call it persistence ignorance. The only things an Insurance object should be aware of, is the parties (customer, Insurance company) and other business concepts such as legal terms.

The most important thing about encapsulation is that the consumer of your class does not need to know about its inner workings in other to use it successfully. Having insurance rely on a static DAO object breaks encapsulation, because its consumer needs to know that a static DAO must exist somewhere or else an exception will occur.

DAO is an implementation detail. Your domain object should not depend on or know about it, ***it*** should depend on your domain object. IoC is a means to ensure more basic things, such as separation of concerns and encapsulation. If by design your are violating these, then no amount of IoC will fix it. As a starting point, I would have a look at my design from a DDD perspective. Have a look at the following question: [Data access layer design in DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365309/data-access-layer-design-in-ddd)

Let me know if this helps.